# How to connect graylog with docker compose to already installed mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, graylog

I have a mongodb already running in my server. and now I want to install graylog using docker-compose file that is [here](https://github.com/Graylog2/docker-compose).

I edited this file like this that I delete mongo service and edit the GRAYLOG_MONGODB_URI that connect to my mongodb.

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  opensearch:
    image: "opensearchproject/opensearch:2.4.0"
    environment:
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      - "bootstrap.memory_lock=true"
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      - "action.auto_create_index=false"
      - "plugins.security.ssl.http.enabled=false"
      - "plugins.security.disabled=true"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        hard: -1
        soft: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - "os_data:/usr/share/opensearch/data"
    restart: "on-failure"

  graylog:
    hostname: "server"
    image: "${GRAYLOG_IMAGE:-graylog/graylog:5.0}"
    depends_on:
      opensearch:
        condition: "service_started"
    entrypoint: "/usr/bin/tini -- wait-for-it opensearch:9200 --  /docker-entrypoint.sh"
    environment:
      GRAYLOG_NODE_ID_FILE: "/usr/share/graylog/data/config/node-id"
      GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET: "${GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET:?Please configure GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET in the .env file}"
      GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2: "${GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2:?Please configure GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2 in the .env file}"
      GRAYLOG_HTTP_BIND_ADDRESS: "0.0.0.0:9000"
      GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI: "http://<server_ip_address>:9000/"
      GRAYLOG_ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: "http://opensearch:9200"
      GRAYLOG_MONGODB_URI: "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/graylog"
    ports:
    - "5044:5044/tcp"   # Beats
    - "5140:5140/udp"   # Syslog
    - "5140:5140/tcp"   # Syslog
    - "5555:5555/tcp"   # RAW TCP
    - "5555:5555/udp"   # RAW TCP
    - "9000:9000/tcp"   # Server API
    - "12201:12201/tcp" # GELF TCP
    - "12201:12201/udp" # GELF UDP
    #- "10000:10000/tcp" # Custom TCP port
    #- "10000:10000/udp" # Custom UDP port
    - "13301:13301/tcp" # Forwarder data
    - "13302:13302/tcp" # Forwarder config
    volumes:
      - "graylog_data:/usr/share/graylog/data/data"
      - "graylog_journal:/usr/share/graylog/data/journal"
    restart: "on-failure"

volumes:
  os_data:
  graylog_data:
  graylog_journal:
```

But when I run the `docker compose up` command, and see graylog logs, I see this in logs and my graylog is not working!

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[graylog.jar:?]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:180) ~[graylog.jar:?]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193) [graylog.jar:?]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:157) [graylog.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[graylog.jar:?]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[graylog.jar:?]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[graylog.jar:?]
```

Comment: As in, MongoDB is not in a container but is already running on the host system; [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)  Is anything wrong with keeping the application-specific MongoDB that's already in your Compose file (maybe changing or removing its `ports:`)?

Comment: In case you are running mongodb as a container already, you need to make sure mongodb and graylog are inside same docker network for service discovery to kick in or you need to make sure ports are exposed and you can connect to it through your host.

In case of host install of mongodb check @DavidMazes answer.

Comment: @DavidMaze host.docker.internal not working
When mongodb in compose file, I try to change port and run it, But it is not working! and I want to have one instance of mongo on my machine for resource-related reasons.

Comment: @matic1123 mongo is not dockerised! it is installed on my machine manyally as a service